Have Harley Quinn and Katana fought before?
The 2024 DC anime Suicide Squad Isekai features two instances where Harley Quinn and Katana fight each other. You'd think that Katana, whose entire schtick is swordfighting—as evidenced by her name—would easily defeat Harley in a swordfight. Surprisingly, Harley holds her own, even when armed with just a baseball bat against Katana's sword.

In their first encounter, Katana takes the win (though not easily), but in their second face-off, Harley turns the tables. She pushes Katana to the point where the sword-wielder is forced to retreat.
This got me wondering about their history. I've tried searching online, but most of the results are either about their Suicide Squad Isekai matchup or hypothetical "who would win?" scenarios.
Have these two characters crossed blades or baseball bats before in the comics or other DC media, or is Suicide Squad Isekai the first time we've seen them fight? If they have clashed before, how did the fight unfold, and who came out on top?

Perhaps Harley has a mentally ill version of sword skills from nothing to lose zen focus  https://www.atmabodha.com/the-servant or she took fencing in college.  See also Fonzie at fencing https://youtu.be/BCLy8Por4fo?si=uSruxEcYusTuGfpd
